# How to find a website which is no longer used?

Tags: c#

How to get the creation date of a website,last modification done on the site using c#.

I dont know how to get the creation date of website.

For last modification date I check the google find many pages on the topic but all they say that it depends on the server to set the date of last modification time header.

My intention is making a software that gives the details about the site when user entered a url and find whether the site is no loger used or not?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about web sites you host on your server, or other company's web sites on the internet.

Comment: I know how to find in my server but consider blogspot.com there are so many blogs that are no longer used..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.  There are many reasons whether or not a site may no longer be available.  This could be due to a domain no longer being registered, no longer having a valid DNS server, no longer having pages on a server, etc.

The bottom line is, there is no software way to know if a site is no longer available.  Someone could, for example, put up a page in its place.  This is often done by cyber squatters to capture old domain names traffic for advertising.

Finally, what you find from your Googling about getting the last modified date is true.  It does depend entirely on the server whether or not the date is sent, and if it accurate at all.  There is no fool proof way to do this.